# regular expression word preceded by char

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to grab a specific string only if a certain word is followed by a `=` sign.

Also, I want to get all the info after that `=` sign until a `/` is reached or the string ends.

Let's take into example:

> somestring.bla/test=123/ohboy/item/item=capture

I want to get `item=capture` but not item alone.

I was thinking about using lookaheads but I'm not sure it this is the way to go. I appreciate any help as I'm trying to grasp more and more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture `item=capture`, it is straightforward:

```
/item=[^\/]*/
```

If you want to also extract the value,

```
/item=([^\/]*)/
```

If you *only* want to match the value, then you need to use a look-*behind*.

```
/(?<=item=)[^\/]*/
```

EDIT: too many errors due to insomnia. Also, screw PHP and its failure to disregard separators in a character group as separators.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But this way I would get everything from action=.

If I had somestring.bla/test=123/ohboy/item/item=capture/stuff, I would grab item=capture/stuff.

Comment: OP doesn't want to run over `/`s... so a lookahead is due at the end of your regexes, of the form `($|(?=/))`, I'd also use `[^/]` instead of a `.` and different delimiters.  A general form might be `#(?<=/)([^/=]+)=([^/]*)(?:$|(?=/))#`

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: Oh, I did not notice "/ is reached". I will edit for that. Regarding "general form", the question asks for "a certain word", I assumed that was "item". "Certain word" is not very general.

Comment: True.  But I wanted to contribute more to the conversation than a minor edit.  "The more you know", right?

Comment: Er... your dollar signs in the first two now hurt more than help.

Comment: Egad, too early in the morning to answer questions :)

Comment: /item=[^/]*/ - awesome.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

```
[^/=]*=[^/]*
```

will give you all the pairs that match your requirements.

So from your example it should return:

> test=123
>
> item=capture

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I wrote some time ago. I modified it a little, and added the `$keys`  argument so that you can specify valid keys:

```
function getKeyValue($string, Array $keys = null) {
    $keys = (empty($keys) ? '[\w\d]+' : implode('|', $keys));
    $pattern = "/(?<=\/|$)(?P<key>{$keys})\s*=\s*(?P<value>.+?)(?=\/|$)/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as & $match) {
        foreach ($match as $key => $value) {
            if (is_int($key)) {
                unset($match[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $matches ?: FALSE;
}
```

Just trow in the string and valid keys:

```
$string = 'somestring.bla/test=123/ohboy/item/item=capture';
$keys = array('test', 'item');
$keyValuePairs = getKeyValue($string, $keys);
var_dump($keyValuePairs);
```